# Which Stack Exchange community is related to queries based on electronic gadgets?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about my JBL Pulse 3, I wanted to know which community could help me in that.

> I want to know if I could connect a JBL Pulse 2 with JBL Pulse 3 using JBL connect.

I obviously googled that but I got no answers.

Comment: Can you please give a brief description of your intended question in your post?

Comment: I would say [Internet of things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: There's been a few failed attempts at a gadgets/consumer electronics.se. Might be able to shoehorn this somewhere else, depending on what the gadget is interfacing with tho...

Comment: @Ano I edited my question.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Oh I see, thank you

Comment: ah. Alas, I cannot be of more help - can't think of any good fits off the top of my head

Comment: You should avoid yes/no questions at all costs, as they are pretty much useless. If someone answered "yes", now what? You still don't know *how* to connect them.  Don't ask if it can be done. State clearly what you are trying to do. State clearly what you have done (including what you have learned from researching), and why that isn't helping you move forward. People can then give you advice on reaching your goal. As for the site this would be appropriate on, in this form, none. Maybe [edit] your question to change *your* question and people will be able to figure out where it belongs?

Comment: Your hypothetical question is a yes/no question.  It's right there: `I want to know if I could connect`. That's answered with a yes or a no.